# How can I highlight a specific div from a hash in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user comes to a website via *www.example.com/#div4*, I would like the division specified in the URL to be highlighted with `#F37736` (orange) and then within 2 seconds transition smoothly back to `#00A087` (the default color).

The `div` to be highlighted as a `class` of "fixed-nav-bar".

What I've tried:

```
var hash = false; 
checkHash();

function checkHash(){ 
  if(window.location.hash != hash) {
    hash = window.location.hash; 
  } t=setTimeout("checkHash()",400); 
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/

Comment: This is not at all clear, what are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look for the hash, then target the division by it's class name. You'll immediately change the color of the `div` to your orange color, then animate it back to your default color.

You will need to include the [jQuery Color library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to animate the `background-color` though, as vanilla jQuery cannot animate `background-color`. You can also use [jQuery UI's highlight effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/), thought the UI library is a little heavier in size.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('.' + hash).css('background-color', '#F37736').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#00A087'
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to use setTimeout instead of animate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422038/highlight-a-specific-div-with-settimeout-from-a-hash-in-the-url-jquery-javascrip

Answer (score 8):

This can be solved with just CSS using the `:target` pseudo-class. It allows you to highlight the item that has an ID matching the hash in your URL. A very simple example of this would be:

```
div {
    background-color: #00A087;
}
div:target {
   background-color: #F37736;
}
```

By default, a `div` would have a default colour but on finding a match it would switch to something different. To make it work in the way you specified, just sprinkle a bit of `animation` magic:

```
div {
    background-color: #00A087;
}
div:target {
    background-color: #F37736;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-name: highlight;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes highlight {
    from {
        background-color: #F37736;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #00A087;
    }
}
```

Here I've set the animation to delay for 2 seconds and to maintain the final state of the animation.

With the various properties available you can mix and match to make it work a little differently but this would achieve what was being asked in the question.

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/cchana/pen/JjbeQPb)

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that, you wanna highlight the background color on some events.
Try adding this css to your code. This will highlight background color on hover.

```
.fixed-nav-bar {
    background-color: #f37736;
}

.fixed-nav-bar:hover {
    background-color: #00a087;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
}
```

Hope this will help you.