# How to count click about dblclick and do something after 4 clicks in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

To let`doSetTag` function take effect, before that and the first clicking(doule click, 2 clicks), some html elements will be highlight displayed, when user click button again(the second double-click, 4 clicks), then `doSetTag(tagid);` takes effect. Below colde takes effect at once double-click(2 clicks), so I would like to count the dbclick and let `doSetTag(tagId)` works after the second double-click(4 clicks).

```
$('#tagLabels .minitag-label').attr('title','Double-Click to cancel the tag').unbind().on('dblclick',function(){
    var labelid = $(this).data('id');
    var labelName = $(this).text();
        if (res.has(tagName) == 1){
            window.location.hash = "#resTags";
            setTimeout(function()
                {
                $(hash).css('background-color', '#D8CEC9').animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#00A087'
                }, 200);
                    doSetTag(tagid);
                },5000);
        }
})
```

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking or needing to accomplish

Comment: can you add the html so we can try to recreate the scenario

Comment: @charlietfl Hi, I updated my question, How to count click about dblclick and do something after 4 clicks in jQuery?

Comment: @KarlL Hi, I updated my question, How to count click about dblclick and do something after 4 clicks in jQuery?

Comment: Put a counter that will count no. of click and if `count = 4` execute your function and reset your count to 0 again

Comment: Yes, I need a counter, but I don't know how and where